# svn merge problems after cvs2svn migration

Tags: svn, merge, branch, cvs2svn

Our team had a cvs repository, which we converted to svn via cvs2svn.  Our repository has a main branch (let's call in `main`), that effectively serves as trunk (even though it was technically branched off from trunk far in the past).

After the cvs2svn conversion, I branched off `main` to `branch`.

I made a small change in `branch`, and then attempted to merge `branch` back into `main`:

```
[~/main] svn merge https:.../branch
```

This should compute the diff to `branch` since the split happened, and apply that diff to `main`.  It goes back a couple years too far back, however, leading to a zillion conflicts.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I've scoured Google but can't find anything.

I know that I can call svn merge and pass in the exact revision numbers.  I'm looking for a better alternative.

Comment: I see no reason to suspect that your problem has any connection to the cvs2svn conversion.

Comment: svn merge depends on correct ancestry information to function correctly.  cvs does not have that information, so cvs2svn tries to make a guess at it.  From what I've read, it is usually good but has trouble with branches-of-branches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell svn merge what your merge point is so it knows what range of commits to sync to main.  Since you didn't specify a range, it defaults to the range of commits through the HEAD revision.  This causes too many revisions.

This will get the previous commit revision that you will be syncing from:

```
svn log --xml --stop-on-copy https://.../branch | grep 'revision=' | head -n 1 | sed 's/.*revision="\([0-9][0-9]*\)".*/\1/g'
```

Basically, that gets the first copy revision on the branch (which I'll call "REV").  You'll then merge that to your 'main' copy's HEAD revision (in the main dir):

```
cd main
svn merge https://.../branch:REV https://.../branch:HEAD .
```

That should apply all changes from REV through HEAD on the 'branch' copy to the 'main' copy.  This should work fine even for repeat merges from branch to main.

Cheers!